# make: *** No rule to make target needed by file, stop

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, shared-libraries

I am using the Makefile below and getting an error

```
info ::
    @echo && echo "%%%% Edu DL %%%%" && echo "Available rules:"
#
# for now just a single build line
#
info ::
    @echo "make testdl : make test application"
LIBSRCS = matrix.cpp net.cpp dataset.cpp layer.cpp funcs.cpp vector.cpp
LIBOBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${LIBSRCS})
INC=-I/usr/local/include/blis
LDFLAGS=-L../../blistest/blis/lib/sandybridge
LDLIBS= -lblis -lm
CPPFLAGS += $(INC)
CXXFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS)


dataset.o : dataset.h matrix.h
matrix.o : matrix.h
funcs.o : funcs.h matrix.h
layer.o : layer.h matrix.h funcs.h
net.o : net.h matrix.h dataset.h layer.h
test.o : matrix.h net.h dataset.h layer.h funcs.h
CXX = clang++ -std=c++17
testdl : test.o ${LIBOBJS}
    @echo "Making test program <<$@>>"
    @${CXX} -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean
info ::
    @echo "make clean : remove junk and executables"
clean ::
    @rm -f *~ *.o a.out testdl
```

And getting the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'libblis.so', needed by 'testdl'.  Stop.
```

Where -L points to the relative location of libblis.so, and I link it with -lblis

Comment: Quite hard to understand how you get that error from that makefile since you don't have libblis.so as a dependency. Are you sure you've told us everything?

Comment: @john I am working off of someone else's Makefile, and trying to add libblis.so to link to it also, so I maybe missing something in the Makefile completely... libblis.so is needed by 'testdl' as it says above, if that is any help?

Comment: does the command `env | fgrep libblis.so` show you something?

Comment: The question is why is make trying to make libblis.so. It doesn't seem to me that you have told it to try to make that file, so I can't understand why you get a message saying that make doesn't know how to make that file.

Comment: @prog-fh I tried both yours and env | grep (relative directory)/libblis.so and both show nothing. But the file does exist in that location alongside libblis.so.3

Comment: @john does make necessarily mean compile? I would imagine it also includes the linking process, which I would need to do

Comment: @IlknurMustafa I think you are missing the point. The error message doesn't say the file doesn't exist (that would be understandable) it says that make doesn't know how to make the file. So the question is why is make trying to make that file. You haven't told it to (as far as I can see).

Comment: If your makefile said something like this `testdl : test.o ${LIBOBJS} libblis.so` then the error would be understandable. But according to what you have posted above, it doesn't.

Comment: @IlknurMustafa The error message shown is from the `makefile` in your previous (now deleted) question.  The `makefile` shown here should not (*can* not) generate that error as far as I can see.

Comment: @IlknurMustafa When asking questions, please post the correct information. Otherwise it's just very confusing.

Comment: @G.M. I can assure I am using this file when using Make, I ran a make clean and then tried making again and this time it built fine. Should have tried this earlier

Comment: @G.M. right now i am getting another error after i've built the project which says 
```Undefined reference to 'somefunction'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1```

Comment: @john to fix above, I changed the line to
```testdl : test.o ${LIBOBJS} libblis.so , now i am getting the error above again
make: no rule to make libblis.so
So I added the relative path to libblis.so again in that same line

Comment: don't you have in your working directory many makefiles (`makefile` with lower `m`, `Makefile` with upper `M` or  `GNUmakefile`) and `make` doesn't use the one you posted?

Comment: @IlknurMustafa Ask yourself this question. Do you want this makefile to make the file `libblis.so`? I'm sure you realise that the answer is no. You want the makefile to **use** that file, but you don't want it to **make** that file. So put that line back how it was. The change you made was wrong, the line should just say `testdl : test.o ${LIBOBJS}`.

Comment: @john Thank you, I reverted the changes. But which change should I make so it links that object?

Comment: @IlknurMustafa I would have thought that `LDFLAGS=-L../../blistest/blis/lib/sandybridge LDLIBS= -lblis -lm` would make the link work. Do you get an error when you have that?

Comment: @IlknurMustafa You've correctly defined the variable `LDLIBS= -lblis -lm` but you don't use it anywhere.  You need to get used to examining the output from `make` to make sure the commands/options/flags etc. used are as you would expect.

Comment: @G.M. oh yes you are right, should I just add CXXFLAGS+=$(LDLIBS) or is the usage rule different